# Dynamically querying the database through route query parameters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am working on a project and I need a single endpoint to return different data based on different route parameters supplied, for example: `api/v1/vendors?asset_type=assetTypeId&get_only_vendors_with_email=true` should give me all the vendors with an assetTypeID supplied and also vendors who have email address. How can I achieve that in Laravel?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
            $query = Vendor::query()->where('account_id', $accountID);
            $query->when(request('get_only_vendors_with_email', false), function ($q, $accountID) {
                return $q->whereNotNull('email_address')->where('account_id', $accountID);
            });

            $query->when(request('get_only_maintenance_vendors', false), function ($q, $accountID) {
                return $q->where('is_maintenance', request('get_only_maintenance_vendors'))->where('account_id', $accountID);
            });
            
            $query->when(request('get_only_purchase_vendors', false), function ($q, $accountID) {
                return $q->where('is_purchase', true)->where('account_id', $accountID);
             });

            $query->when(request('get_only_maintenance_vendors', false), function ($q, $accountID) {
                return $q->where('is_maintenance', request('get_only_maintenance_vendors'))->where('account_id', $accountID);
            });
            $vendors = $vendorQuery->get();
```

Comment: where is asset_type ?

Comment: It should come from the url.  Something like this: api/v1/vendors?asset_type=2&get_only_vendors_with_email=true. You get? @Hamid Shariati

Comment: your question isn't clear. What was the expected output? when you tried, what data it returned which is different from expected?

Answer (score 0):

It's missing a `when` check for the `asset_type` param. Add this:

```
$query->when(request('asset_type'), function ($q) {
    return $q->where('asset_type', request('asset_type');
});
```

Also, if your first statement was

```php
$query = Vendor::query()->where('account_id', $accountID);
```

Why do you add the where query for `account_id` in each `when` call?

You can simplify it like this:

```php
$query = Vendor::query()->where('account_id', $accountID);

$query->when(request('get_only_vendors_with_email', false), function ($q) {
    return $q->whereNotNull('email_address');
});

$query->when(request('get_only_maintenance_vendors', false), function ($q) {
    return $q->where('is_maintenance', request('get_only_maintenance_vendors'));
});
            
$query->when(request('get_only_purchase_vendors', false), function ($q) {
    return $q->where('is_purchase', true);
});

$query->when(request('get_only_maintenance_vendors', false), function ($q) {
    return $q->where('is_maintenance', request('get_only_maintenance_vendors'));
});

$query->when(request('asset_type'), function ($q) {
    return $q->where('asset_type', request('asset_type');
});

$vendors = $query->get();
```